# Can we replace Math.floor by ~ and still get the same result?

Tags: javascript, rounding

I see that by replacing this line of code

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
```

by this one:

```
~(Math.random() * 10
```

I get the same result, why is that ?

Comment: Well, only one has a syntax error, so the answer would be "no".

Comment: Unless you mean `~ = Math.floor`?

Comment: Yes, with caveats, but you arguably shouldn't.

Comment: What benefit does this confer, other than marginally less typing?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica worse performance and reduced readability are only some of the many benefits such a change would provide!

Comment: `~` is more of a `Math.ceil()` in this case.

Comment: No because they do not work the same. For example any negative number: `Math.floor(-10.3) => -11` vs `~(-10.3) => 9`. Also `~` is less readable.

Comment: What is the reason of this except to confuse the guy who has to maintain it whether this was intentional or an error? Just `Math.floor` and people know that it should happen.

Comment: Given that `Math.random() * 10` is a non-negative number, you can use [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) for the same effect as `Math.floor`.

Comment: Did you mean `~~`, which takes the one's complement of a following number after converting it to a signed 32 bit integer, followed by taking the one's complement of the result - thereby reversing the sign inversion of the first one's complement operation.. Of note  `Math.floor` takes a wider range of operand values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, since they don´t work the same. The `~` NOT operator inverts the bits of a integer, so if you have the binary number `0101` (5 in decimal), the operator would return:

```
~0101 = 1010;  // ~5 = 10
```

But since JavaScript uses *32-bit signed integer*, the result would be different:

```
~00000000000000000000000000000101 = 11111111111111111111111111111010  // ~5 = -6
```

---

The `Math.floor()` function returns the maximum integer less or equal to a number, so using the same example with number 5:

```
Math.floor(5) // ==> would return 5
```

You can see that both operators return different values.
However, it is possible to simulate a `Math.Floor()` function using the `~` operator in float number, just multiplying `* -1` the number and then substracting `- 1` to the result, but **I hardly don´t reccommend it** as it makes the code less legigable:

```js
const number = 5.56;

console.log(~number  * -1 - 1);    // returns 5

console.log(Math.floor(number));  // returns 5
```

To sum up, they are differents operator, each of them has his own funcionality.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, it's syntax, so you'll have to type something to round a float down to an int.

Either Math.floor() or parseInt().

If you wanted to shorten the typing for yourself you could create a short named function that returns the same result:

```js
function mf(number){
  return Math.floor(number);
}

console.log(mf(Math.random() * 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
parseInt(yourvalue)
```

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek can you provide an example where this fails?

Comment: May of misread the question, though it was specifically asking if `~` can replace `Math.floor`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I see. It's possible that I have misunderstood it. Let's see the asker's input. If this answer is incorrect for the reason you gave, then I will remove it.

Comment: Don't do this. `parseInt` is meant to be called on strings.